# connection string and query works for SqlAlchemy but not records

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, record

Since records is just a thin wrapper around SqlAlchemy, why doesn't this work?  Both of the two ways of running the same query from the same database use the exact same connection string and query.  What gives?  The error I see from print(row) is throws sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
  r'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
  r'Server=server;'
  r'Database=database;'
  r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
  )

  import urllib
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine

  pp = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect{}'.format(urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str))
  engine = create_engine(pp)
  cnxn = engine.connect()
  rows = cnxn.execute('select * from mysmalltable').fetchall()
  print(rows)
    cnxn.close()

  import records
  db = records.Database(pp)
  rows = db.query('select * from mysmalltable')
  for row in rows:
      print(row) #throws sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

 db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
  rows = db.query('select * from mysmalltable')
```

to:

```
  rows = db.query('select * from mysmalltable', fetchall=True)
```

Although this isn't very practical for large recordsets it was the only way I could get it to work (or I get the same error as you).